# Error with a player turn ending loop in the Zombie Dice game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to develop a code for the zombie dice game.

My problem is when the first player replies that he doesn't want to continue playing.

The game ends and I can't get the second player to play. Can someone help me?

```
import random

print("========== ZOMBIE DICE (PROTÓTIPO SEMANA 4) ==========")
print("========= WELCOME TO THE ZOMBIE DICE GAME! ========")
numeroJogadores = 0
while numeroJogadores < 2:
  numeroJogadores = int(input("Enter the number of players: "))
  print(numeroJogadores)

  if numeroJogadores < 2:
    print("NOTICE: You must have at least 2 players to continue!")

  listaJogadores = []
  
  for i in range(numeroJogadores):

    nome = str(input("\nEnter player name: " + str(i+1) + ": "))
    listaJogadores.append(nome)

  print(listaJogadores)

  dadoVerde = ("brain", "steps", "brain", "shot", "steps", "brain")
  dadoAmarelo = ("shot", "steps", "brain", "shot", "steps", "brain")
  dadoVermelho = ("shot", "steps", "shot", "brain", "steps", "shot")

  listaDados = [dadoVerde, dadoVerde, dadoVerde, dadoVerde, dadoVerde, dadoVerde, 
                dadoAmarelo, dadoAmarelo, dadoAmarelo, dadoAmarelo, 
                dadoVerde, dadoVermelho, dadoVermelho]

  print("\nSTARTING THE GAME...")

  jogadorAtual = 0
  dadosSorteados = []
  tiros = 0
  cerebros = 0
  passos = 0

  while True:

    print("PLAYER TURN: ", listaJogadores[jogadorAtual])

    
    for i in range (3):
      numeroSorteado = random.randint(0, 12)
      dadoSorteado = listaDados[numeroSorteado]

      if (dadoSorteado == dadoVerde):
        corDado = "Green"
      elif (dadoSorteado == dadoAmarelo):
        corDado = "Yellow"
      else:
        corDado = "Red"

      print("Dice Drawn: ", corDado)

      dadosSorteados.append(dadoSorteado)

    print("\nThe faces drawn were: ")

    for dadoSorteado in dadosSorteados:
      numeroFaceDado = random.randint(0,5)

      if dadoSorteado[numeroFaceDado] == "brain":
        print("- brain (you ate a brain)")
        cerebros = cerebros + 1
      elif dadoSorteado[numeroFaceDado] == "tiro":
        print("- shot (you got shot)")
        tiros = tiros + 1
      else:
        print("- steps (a victim escaped)")
        passos = passos + 1

    print("\nCURRENT SCORE: ")
    print("brins: ", cerebros)
    print("shots: ", tiros)

    if cerebros >= 13:
      print("Congratulations, you've won the game!")
      break
    elif tiros >= 3:
      print("You lost the game!")
      break
    else:
      continuarTurno = str(input("\nNOTICE: Do you want to continue playing dice? (y=yes / n=no)")).lower()
      if continuarTurno == "n":
        jogadorAtual = jogadorAtual + 1
        dadossorteados = 0
        tiros = 0
        cerebros = 0
        passos = 0

        if jogadorAtual > numeroJogadores:
          print("Finalizing the game prototype")
      else:
        print("Starting another round of the current turn")
        dadossorteados = []

print("======================================================")
print("===================== END OF THE GAME ====================")
print("======================================================")
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm new as a programmer. If anyone knows how to help me with this problem, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Well now the code just works. I can switch players just fine, but if you go through all the characters it crashes again since `jogadorAtual` gets too big for `listaJogadores`. I don't quite understand the game, but assuming you want to start back with the first player, an elegant way you can accomplish that is by doing modulus with the `%` operator, which divides two numbers but returns the remainder. If you divide the number of players by the size of `listaJogadores`, you'll always get a number inside `listaJogadores`'s range.

```
# Change this...
print("PLAYER TURN: ", listaJogadores[jogadorAtual])

# ...to this
print("PLAYER TURN: ", listaJogadores[jogadorAtual % len(listaJogadores)])
```

If that's not what you need for your game, let me know.

---

Original answer: Is the game ending or is it *crashing*? When I run the game, it always crashes with:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 56, in <module>
    diceDrawns.append(diceDrawn)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

This is because after looping, you try to do `diceDrawns.append()`, but you've already replaced the `diceDrawns` list with an integer on line 87. I'm not sure if you meant to replace `diceDrawn` instead, but that's definitely the source of the problem.

An unrelated note: You can do `+=` as a shorthand way to increment a variable by a certain amount, so you can replace a lot of instances of things like `currentPlayer = currentPlayer + 1` with `currentPlayer += 1`, and the same can be done with *any* operator, so you could also do things like `-=` or `*=`

Comment: @thisismy-stackoverflowavatar I ended up translating the name of the variables and it actually generated this error. Sorry about that.
I updated the code in the original way. I just translated the sentences.

Comment: @RodrigoFiadPasini Well now the code just works. I can switch players just fine, but if you go through all the characters it crashes again since `jogadorAtual` gets too big for `listaJogadores`. I updated my answer for how you can solve that as well.